# What is an effective way to hunt animals with a wooden spear?

Tags: rust

I am kind of new to *Rust* and I am struggling badly to hunt, e.g. for a horse. It keeps running away, even if I sneak and am behind it's back. I do not have cloth to make a bow, and I had no luck to find wolves or bears that I could just charge. What are the most effective ways of hunting animals that run? I also know that you can throw the spear, but my aim is terrible, unless he is about 2-3 meters away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two spears will bring down just about any animal.

Practice throwing a spear into a tree or something. You can get a sense of distance and aim.

- Approach horse slowly and quietly using crouch
- Throw first spear (Horse will bolt and run)
- Run down the horse until it stops running
- Throw second spear
- Harvest that delicious uncooked wolf meat from its lifeless body

Once you kill an animal or two you should have enough cloth to construct a bow.

If you use a bone knife you will harvest more than by using a rock or other crude tool.

Comment: Thanks. I asked this because you need cloth for a bow. You can get 20 cloth from hemp fibers